# Fatal Exception : AsyncTask #1

Tags: android

help help..huu

Im having a problem here..seems there was no error in codes..but when I run it...and click button to view map consist routing the map..It appers to be close all of sudden..why is that? Please help me friends..

Im developing an app to read my current location and creating route to A position..

here are the codes:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

    onNewIntent(getIntent());

    Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
    Drawable marked_places = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.feringgi_map);

    mymap = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mymap);
    controller = mymap.getController();
    // extract MapView from layout
    mymap.getController().setZoom(15);
    mymap.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mymap.setSatellite(false);

    // create an overlay that shows our current location
    myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mymap);

    // add this overlay to the MapView and refresh it
    mymap.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay); 
    mymap.postInvalidate();

    myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            controller.setZoom(10);
            controller.animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());                
        }
    });

    zoomToMyLocation();

   switch(selecteditem)
   {
   case 0:        switch(selectedsubitem){
            case 0://Place A       
                    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
                  Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                      if (location !=null) {
                      loc=location;
                  }
                  GeoPoint destination = getPoint(3.144341, 101.69541800000002);
                  new BackgroundTask(this, loc, destination).execute();
                break;              
}
}

 class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private Location location;
        private GeoPoint dest;
        private Route route;
        private Activity activity;
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private RouteOverlay routeOverlay;

        public BackgroundTask(Activity activity, Location loc, GeoPoint dest) {
            location=loc; 
            this.dest=dest;
            this.activity=activity;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setTitle("Loading...");
            dialog.setMessage("Calculating Route...");
            dialog.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                  cancel(true);
                  MyMap.this.finish();
                }});
            dialog.show();
        }

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                if(isNetworkAvailable())
                {
                    if(haveInternet())
                    {   try{
                            route = directions(new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1.0E6),(int)(location.getLongitude()*1.0E6)), dest); 
                        }
                        catch (NullPointerException e){ }
                    }
                    else
                    {   return null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {   return null; }

                return null;
                }
```

And this is the log cat (updated).. :

```
    12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10228 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:728)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:378)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at com.madcatworld.testtesttest.MyMap$BackgroundTask.isNetworkAvailable(MyMap.java:488)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at com.madcatworld.testtesttest.MyMap$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(MyMap.java:411)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at com.madcatworld.testtesttest.MyMap$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(MyMap.java:1)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-10 13:30:36.677: E/AndroidRuntime(13405):    ... 5 more
```

this is the other half I havent post them here previously:

```
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405): Activity com.madcatworld.testtesttest.MyMap has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4254bb28 that was originally added here
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.madcatworld.testtesttest.MyMap has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4254bb28 that was originally added here
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at com.madcatworld.testtesttest.MyMap$BackgroundTask.onPreExecute(MyMap.java:406)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at com.madcatworld.testtesttest.MyMap.onCreate(MyMap.java:108)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
12-10 13:30:37.308: E/WindowManager(13405):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my manifest file:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.madcatworld.testtesttest"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

            <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mymap"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:apiKey="XXXX"
            />       

            <activity
                android:theme="@style/StyledIndicators"
                android:name=".MainTest"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
            <activity android:name="A"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
            <activity android:name="B"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
            <activity android:name="C"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

For your information, I already put ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE in my manifest..

Can u discover what cause the error? No error in code..but it failed to review my route map..:( Thanks Friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> E/AndroidRuntime(5368): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException:
>   ConnectivityService: Neither user 10228 nor current process has
>   android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

make sure you have  added `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file as

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

EDIT :

remove

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
android:id="@+id/mymap"
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:apiKey="XXXX"
/>
```

this code from `AndroidManifest.xml` and put it inside any xml layout within res/layout folder in your project

Comment: Yeah..Ive forgot to add that..thanks! Already did..but the problem remain the same.. :(

Comment: post your AndroidManifest.xml also

Comment: Why remove this com.google.android.maps.MapView from manifest file? It used to work just like that. Did they change something? I havent touched the maps for a while now.

Comment: which mean I need to create new xml file to seperate them? is that what u mean?

Comment: He is right. Refer to this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/

Comment: @NadirahIbtisam : you have map.xml layout in res/layout folder. put it in map.xml layout or if not then create a new one

Comment: Hi guys, ρяσѕρєя K and @Lazy Ninja.. already removed the code in manifest..thanks..:) (My mistakes is that, previously i paste them in both manifest and map.xml) But..the PROBLEM remain the same..it seems like it is not related with that :(

Comment: @NadirahIbtisam : now what error you are getting? make sure you are extending MapActivity ?

Comment: its not 'him'..its her @Lazy Ninja :D Thanks for the link

Comment: public class MyMap extends MapActivity implements LocationListener

Comment: @NadirahIbtisam : k now post latest logcat result when application is crashing

Comment: Done, I post every error I had in log cat.. sigh .. thanks ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: @NadirahIbtisam : just comment out `new BackgroundTask(this, loc, destination).execute();` line and see your application is running without crashing or not

Comment: Yeah it works, and no crash if i comment that..but It will NOT call the method for routing the path in google map.. the result will only display my current location..

Comment: @NadirahIbtisam : ProgressDialog is creating problem you can search fro this error i'm sure u will find more results just search for"WindowLeaked: Activity com.madcatworld.testtesttest.MyMap has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl" thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to your log you don't have this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

This permission allows you to access the state of network device (Wifi, 3G, bluetooth, etc..) of your
device

Comment: Yeah..Ive forgot to add that..thanks! Already did..but the problem remain the same.. :(

Comment: already did.. but it keep saying as it isn't in the logcat.. fiuhhh

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but it seems you get this because you try to check network availability from do in background. Can you try to check it in onpreexecute?

Comment: yes, I usually check network availability in main thread that is just before "new BackgroundTask(this, loc, destination).execute();". I think it should work if you put the check over there

Comment: the check? how to do that @Droider

Comment: I mean put isNetworkAvailable() before "new BackgroundTask(this, loc, destination).execute(). This should probably work